# Swift 3 Core Data check

Tags: swift, core-data

I would like to know how I can check if an object already exists inside my Core Data

And sorry I´m new to Swift:

```
var category = ["Privat","Studium","Termine"]

class AddTaskViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropDown: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var textFieldTask: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var isImport: UISwitch!

    //array of entety need to read it for check if object exist
    var catCheck : [ToDoCat] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getData()

        for i in 0..<category.count
        {

            print(category[i])


            let testen = ToDoCat(context: (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext)

             // here I need to test if the element is existing inside the core data
            testen.cat = category[i]

        }
        //save the data to coredata.
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext();

    }
```

The part where I need to check for the object's existence is commented in the code above

Comment: You need to fetch the data once and use the `filter` or `index(of` function. By the way, don't use index based loops if the index isn't used at all actually, Swift knows Fast Enumeration )`for aCategory in category { ...`

Comment: do you have an example for that ?  Or a documentation where i can find it ? Couldn't find anything so far.

Comment: Core Data `fetch` is a basic and essential task. Every Core Data tutorial implements code to do a fetch. You get an array of `NSManagedObject` items, then compare your current category against the corresponding attribute. A second option is to fetch the data using a predicate in each iteration of the loop but this is much more expensive.

Comment: thanks for help :) I´m trying my best!